# How to Change Item's Order in a List View?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to allow users to change the order of photos in the list. Tinder has something like that. I'm trying to add a drag gesture to the item but nothing happened.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Row: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let cells: [Cell]
}

struct Cell: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let imageURL: String
    @State var offset = CGSize.zero
}

struct PhotosView: View {
    
    @State var rows = [Row(cells: [Cell(imageURL: "gigi"), Cell(imageURL: "hadid"), Cell(imageURL: "gigihadid")]), Row(cells: [Cell(imageURL: "gigi"), Cell(imageURL: "hadid")])]
    
    var body: some View {
                List {
                    ForEach(rows) { row in
                        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing:15) {
                            ForEach(row.cells) { cell in
                                Image(cell.imageURL)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFill()
                                    .frame(maxWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 3.6)
                                    .clipped()
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                                    .offset(x: cell.offset.width, y: cell.offset.height)
                                    .gesture(
                                        DragGesture()
                                            .onChanged { gesture in
                                                cell.offset = gesture.translation
                                            }

                                            .onEnded { _ in
                                                if abs(cell.offset.width) > 100 {
                                                    // remove the card
                                                } else {
                                                    cell.offset = .zero
                                                }
                                            }
                                    )
                            }
                            if row.cells.count < 3 {
                                ZStack{
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                        .fill(Color(UIColor.systemGray6))
                                    Button(action: {}, label: {
                                        Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.fill.badge.plus")
                                            .font(.title)
                                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray3))
                                    })
                                }
                            }
                        }.padding(.vertical)
                    }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                }.padding(.top, UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 8)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

What view looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

I only want users can change the order of photos via drag gesture.